How to Directly Set SMTP Credentials in Laravel Mailer Without Using Config Values?
I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to send emails with different SMTP credentials for each email. Instead of setting these credentials in the configuration files, I want to directly pass them to the Mail::mailer() method within my job.
Sometimes the configuration values are not set properly, and the email is sent using the credentials from the last email sent. Why does this happen, and how can I ensure that the correct credentials are always used?
Here is what I have so far:

class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected $recipient,
        protected $content,
        protected $subject,
        protected $emailLog,
        protected $emailDraftSettings,
        protected $processedVideo,
    ) {
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        try {        
            // Change default mail sending config values
            $emailDraftSettings = $this->emailDraftSettings;
            config([
                'mail.default' => 'smtp_email_sender',
                'mail.mailers.smtp_email_sender.username' => $emailDraftSettings->from_email_id,
                'mail.mailers.smtp_email_sender.password' => $emailDraftSettings->from_email_password,
                'mail.from.address' => $emailDraftSettings->from_email_id,
                'mail.from.name' => $emailDraftSettings->name
            ]);
           
            Mail::to($this->recipient)
                ->send(new BusinessInquiryEmail($this->content, $this->subject));
            $this->emailLog->is_email_sent = EmailLog::SENT;
            $this->emailLog->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->emailLog->is_email_sent = EmailLog::FAILED;
            $this->emailLog->failure_reason = $e->getMessage();
            $this->emailLog->save();
            Log::error('Error occurred while sending email: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

I expected each email to be sent with the correct SMTP credentials provided at runtime, without relying on the last used configuration values.

it is not a good idea use config() for that because overriding the original application config could have weird result when the email is sent at same time from different php process.
if you realy want to use native laravel Mail::mailer() theres no easy solution.
I think that "Override Email Config with setSymfonyTransport and createSymfonyTransport" could be one of the best solution, maybe this link can help you:
https://medium.com/@moaminsharifi/how-to-send-email-in-laravel-using-custom-config-per-email-laravel-11-0cb6b84ca0b8
